# Calculate skewness in base R

Tags: r, skewness, moments

I'm working on my literacy in math notation and statistics in general, using the R language as a means of translating formulas as I read through textbooks and teach myself.

I'm trying to write [Pearson's moment coefficient of skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Pearson%27s_moment_coefficient_of_skewness) in base R.

If I crack open the `moments` package in R and inspect the `skewness` source I can see the below equation is used to calculate skewness:
$$\frac{E[(X-\mu)^3]}{(E[X-\mu)^2])^{3/2}}$$

```
n <- length(X)
(sum((X - mean(X))^3)/n)/(sum((X - mean(X))^2)/n)^(3/2)
```

The wikipedia article states that
$$
E\big[\big(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\big)^3\big]
=
\frac{E[(X-\mu)^3]}{(E[X-\mu)^2])^{3/2}}$$

which I have interpreted as

```
mean((X - mean(X)) / sd(X))^3)
```

But if I test the two formulas

```
X = ggplot2::mpg$hwy

n <- length(X)
(sum((X - mean(X))^3)/n)/(sum((X - mean(X))^2)/n)^(3/2)
# 0.366865

mean(((X-mean(X))/sd(X))^3)
# 0.3645158
```

Close but not quite. Grateful for any pointing in the right direction.

Comment: The difference is due to the n-1 in the usual Bessel corrected sample standard deviation. In R I usually just do `mean(scale(x)^3)`, (putting 4 in for 3 if I want kurtosis), but I'm usually unfussed about whether to use n-1 or n.

Comment: If you look at at [Wikipedia's three expressions for sample skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Sample_skewness) your $0.366865$ is $g_1$, your $0.3645158$ is $b_1$, while something like $0.369236$ would be $G_1$